# Flutter Provider "notifyListener()" does not change the state

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have a method `login` in my Provider class which is called in `initState()` method of my `HomeScreen()`, in `login function` I basically register/check if a user information is stored in server or not, and then I post request to server to get that user's info. Everything is working fine **but** when I `hot restart` or `reopens` the app, it keeps on loading because obviously the ternary operation doesn't satisfy but If I print the data inside the `login` function, it does get changed, so as a result, the `notifyListeners()` is not working properly and hence the state is not getting changed. (Right now I have to `hot reload` `ctrl+s`, and then the state changes and everything loads successfully).

HomeScreen():

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<Course> courses = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    courses = Course().getAllCourses();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
      Provider.of<LoginProvider>(context, listen: false).login();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isLoading =
        Provider.of<LoginProvider>(context, listen: false).isLoading;
    User user = Provider.of<LoginProvider>(context, listen: false).user;
    print("INITIAL: $isLoading");
    print("INITIAL: ${user.data!.categoryList!.length}");

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: !isLoading && user.data != null
          ? ListView.separated(
              itemCount: courses.length,
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Divider();
              },
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final course = courses[index];
                final courseNew = user.data!.categoryList![index];
                print("INSIDE: $isLoading");
                print("INSIDE: ${user.data!.categoryList!.length}");
                if (courses.length == user.data!.categoryList!.length) {
                  return ... // full custom
                }
                return Center(
                  child: Text("No Data recieved from backend"),
                );
              },
            )
          : Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              strokeWidth: 4,
            )),
    );
  }
}
```

(Both `courses` and `user.data.categoryList` have same length)

Login function in Provider file:

```
login() async {
    await _checkIsUserLoggedIn();
    if (_deviceDetails.deviceID == "") {
      print("[INFO] NEW USER DEVICE DETECTED");
      print("[INFO] LOGGING IN...");

      await _getDeviceDetails();
      // fetching platform details, if success, carry-on, else throw error

      try {
        if (_deviceDetails.deviceID != "") {
          // post request to server
          Map<String, dynamic> requestBody = {
            'device_id': _deviceDetails.deviceID
          };

          http.Response response = await http
              .post(Uri.parse(Constants.LOGIN_ENDPOINT), body: requestBody);

          _user = userFromJson(response.body);
          _deviceDetails.userID = _user.data!.userId!;
          _deviceDetails.userName = _user.data!.name!;
          _deviceDetails.token = _user.data!.token!;

          await _saveLoginDetails(_deviceDetails);
          print("[INFO] USER LOGGED IN SUCCESSFULLY");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        print("[INFO] ERROR WHILE FETCHING DEVICE DETAILS: $error");
      }
    } else {
      print("[INFO] THIS USER DEVICE IS ALREADY LOGGED IN");
      print("[INFO] FETCHING EXISTING USER DETAILS");

      Map<String, dynamic> requestBody = {'device_id': _deviceDetails.deviceID};

      http.Response response = await http
          .post(Uri.parse(Constants.LOGIN_ENDPOINT), body: requestBody);
      _user = userFromJson(response.body);
      print("INSIDE LOGIN FUNCTION: ${_user.data!.categoryList!.length}"); // prints 2 in console (correct)
    }
    _isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Console output:

Output when app first loads or Hot Restart:

```
I/flutter ( 3495): INITIAL: true
I/flutter ( 3495): INITIAL: 1
I/flutter ( 3495): [INFO] THIS USER DEVICE IS ALREADY LOGGED IN
I/flutter ( 3495): [INFO] FETCHING EXISTING USER DETAILS
I/flutter ( 3495): INSIDE LOGIN FUNCTION: 2
```

Ouput when app Hot Reloads (Ctrl+S):

```
I/flutter ( 3495): INITIAL: false
I/flutter ( 3495): INITIAL: 2
I/flutter ( 3495): INSIDE: false
I/flutter ( 3495): INSIDE: 2
I/flutter ( 3495): INSIDE: false
I/flutter ( 3495): INSIDE: 2
```

As you can see, after hot reloading, the state changes but not without it, so that means `notifyListeners()` is not behaving properly in `login` function?

What could possible be wrong here, I'm really confused...

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set listen to `true` when you are expecting updates:

```
 bool isLoading =
        Provider.of<LoginProvider>(context, listen: true).isLoading;
    User user = Provider.of<LoginProvider>(context, listen: true).user;
```

Comment: It worked! If we do not provide `listen` argument, it is not set to `true` by default? and I have read somewhere that if we do not provider `listen` argument, `notifyListeners()` will keep on updating the widget...

Comment: It will not work as desired without setting listen:true. You basically need to tell it, because logically, you already know what you want your function to do.
Something to keep in mind, is if you want to use your provider inside an `onPressed`. There, you only have the option to set listen:false, otherwise it will throw an error. But this is not the case in your post. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   Class LogInProvider{
    
        bool _isLogin = false; 
   
        setIsLogin(bool isLogin){
           _isLogin = isLogin;

          notifyListeners();

         }
         isLogin(){
           return _isLogin;
          }


     }
```

Then in the ui class .

Get LoginInfo :

```
...
  child : Consumer<LoginInProvider>(
  builder: (context,_loginProvider, child) {
    return Text("${_loginProvider.isLogin}");
  },
```

SetLogin Info :

```
  Provider.of<LoginInfoProvider>(context).setIslogIn(true);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, Can you explain your answer a bit? and what was wrong with my code?

Comment: Basically, notifyListeners() work like setState({}) means it will call the build function again that's why it is calling again and again. Now we case use consumer to wrap the section will be updated then the variable will update .